# Android delete from listview, user experience

Tags: iphone, android, listview, element

I've seen how iphone users delete from lists - its generally a swipe action and then shows some minus/remove button.

I realize that it is counterproductive to implement iphone things on android because android users don't know this stuff.

I don't want to do that, I just don't know of a better/intuitive way to delete from a listview.

I've previously opted for doing "longclicks" on listview items, which will show an alertdialog asking if you want to delete or do other things, but this is never an obvious thing to do.

I've seen delete buttons that are shown in each view, but that messes with the layout of the listview, in a way that wasnt' considered in the wireframes.

What is a good intuitive way to allow the user to remove items from listviews on android?

Comment: I really don't see how swiping a list item is any more intuitive than longclicking one, especially when the list item background fade animation lets the user know something is happening.  My friends with Android phones (who aren't developers), I've found, feel the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my two cents before I pitch my answer. Any one who has an android phone is going to know or eventually find out that longclicks often lead to another menu. Yes, it's not immediately obvious but they are going to figure it out just as iphone users have figured out the swipe action is to delete.

If you really want a fool proof way for a user to know how to delete, I would implement `checkBoxes`. (More on check boxes [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#Checkbox))If the user checks the item, bring up a "soft menu" at the bottom that has a bunch of options normally associated with long clicks.

If you look at the gmail application and check a box, you'll see what I mean when I say "soft menu".

Another way you could go would be to implement check box, then have "menu options." Every android user should be able to see and figure out the menu button on their device, all devices have them. Make one of the menu options **delete** and you're all set.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html#options_menu

Comment: There is a very good example of how to do this in the MessageListAdapter which is used in the stock Android email app and (presumably) the Gmail app as well. See [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/email/activity/MessageList.java;h=d2d652359097f7d2eff597840aa74ef4390b27a9;hb=HEAD) for the source.

Comment: I checked out what you were saying with the gmail app, very intuitive! they also do the long click but you don't have to!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that long click is horrible, but it is the standard on Android; people are more likely to be able to discover using this than any alternative gesture.

Also, put in a delete menu item on the Activity you get to after selecting something from the ListView.

Comment: just wondering why you think a long click is horrible? About as horrible / non-intuitive as a swipe - in both cases one needs to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In my view you should add checkbox to your list view and give a separate button for deleting items from list I mean to say that add a delete button in the layout in which your list view is also present and when user checks the item which he/she wants to delete and click on the delete button,the item which is checked by the user gets remove from list.