# Android approach to deleting an item from a ListView? Switch item layout during runtime

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have read this topic: [Android delete from listview, user experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603341/android-delete-from-listview-user-experience) and since I have a different idea how to go about deleteing an item from a list here is what I had in mind.

I must say I did not code this yet, I am heaving some problems with doing what I want so any help on technical side is also welcome.

Since there is the new action bar, I added a menu option Delete and set it to be shown in the action bar of my ListView. Next I was planning to make that menu option checkable so I can somehow highlite the Delete option in the action bar, for example for it to seem like it is in state pressed, something like a ToggleButton. After pressing the delete button, every item in my list gets a checkbox at the end. I don't wat to display checkbox on my list items all the time because I don't want it to take any available space that from the data I am showing. After the user checks items to be deleted and (un)presses Delete button, data will be deleted. There can be an optional 'Are you sure?' dialog just to confirm deletion.

What do you say about this approach?

I must say, I might be very wrong since I started programming android without heaving an android phone..yet. I plan to get one soon and see if there is a uniform approach to list item deletion that everyobody is using and that I can implement so I don't offer users in my app something not intuitive.

Now some technical questions. Would it be better to have a different leyout for the list item when I am in delete mode or should I maybe add a check box in code? If that is possible at all. At the moment I am trying to set my adapter to be in normal or in delete mode, and with regard to that return a different item view (layout) but it's not working for some reason.

Thank you for your replys and suggestions.

**PART SOLUTION?**
So I found a workaround. I still have a 'Delete' menu option in the action bar and when I click it I set the list in delete mode, just a flag in my code. But my adapter now checkes if this flag is true and if it is whevever I click on a list item I select it. Selecting I do in such a way that in my data I have made a variable that I set or unset. According to this variable my adapter sets a background color of an item in a list thus marking it for deletion.

**BUT** now I have another problem. I can not force my menu item 'Delete' in the action bar to change color when selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Just found out about ViewSwitcher, maybe that will work because I tried to inflate a different layout in my custom adapter and that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can display the checkbox default so user knows that with this checkbox they can do some multiple task like deleting and any other. And the other way if you don't have space for the checkbox you can start another activity which have listview items with the checkbox.

Now in the option menu having Delete option and from them open the context menu having option Delete All or Delete Selected. If user select delete all then clear the list item into the listview or in selected check the checkbox status in for loop check which are checked that item will be remove from list.

After delete update the adapter using this method `youradapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();`.

Check [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) article for checkbox with listview

Comment: Hi Pratik, thank you for you suggestion but when switching layouts I would have to pay attention to current view of the list, remember the position it was scrolled to and set another listview to the same position. I found a workaround but I will write it in the answer field, partly because I have another question :)